# How to implement oauth security protocol on my website (tomcat+jersey+hibernate)

Tags: java, oauth

I have a website with tomcat 7 as a server and mysql db.
Also, I have a few rest services (jersey).
Now I want to implement a login to my website with user and password through iOS/Android devices and to secure all rest services.
I heard about the oauth protocol and it seems very good for my needs but I can't find any good tutorial on the net how to add this oauth protocol to my website.
Do you have good tutorials for me with code examples? 
Thanks